# Making a grid of squares separated by distance of 10 in Java

Tags: java

I have a question regarding creating a grid of squares. I used nested for loops to create at 9X9 grid of squares however I cannot figure out how to make the sides of any two neighboring squares separated by a distance of 10. Below is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import com.programwithjava.basic.DrawingKit;

public class CreateGrid {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DrawingKit dk = new DrawingKit("Grid");

        int x = 10, y = 30, width = 20, height = 20, step = 10;


        //make 9x9 grid
        for (int column = 0; column < 10; column ++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < 10 ; row ++) {
                //draw the rectangles
                Rectangle2D.Float square = new Rectangle2D.Float(x, y, width * row, height * column);
                dk.draw(square);


            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Uh, why do you have both a numberofsquares and a numberofSquares variable? It appears that neither are used.

Comment: Sorry that shouldn't be there. Do you have any input on how to separate the squares

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters, here you are not drawing a grid of squares, but a bunch of overlapping rectangles. All of the rectangles drawn have a corner at (10,30), since you never change the x and y coords.

The proper way of doing this would be to leave both width and height constant at 20, and changing the x/y coords in your nested for loops. The following should do the job

```
// There is no need for separate width/height since it is a square
int size = 20;
// Add the required gap between squares to the size
int displacement = size + 10;
for (int column = 0; column < 10; column ++) {
    for (int row = 0; row < 10 ; row ++) {
        //draw the rectangles
        Rectangle2D.Float square = new Rectangle2D.Float(x + (displacement * row), y + (displacement * column), size, size);
        dk.draw(square);
    }
}
```

Edit: Also, this will make a 10*10 grid, not a 9*9, since you are counting from 0 to 9 inclusive.